# SwiftUI - KV Observe completion from Combine does not get triggered

Tags: swift, swiftui, key-value-observing, combine

I am trying to build a `VOIP` app using lib called `VailerSIPLib`. As the library was built using `Obj-C` and heavily using `NotificationCenter` to to publish the changes the active states all over the place.

I currently at the `CallView` part of the project, I can manage to start, end, reject calls. However, I need to implement `connectionStatus` in the view which will give information about the call like duration, "connecting..", "disconnected", "ringing" etc.

The below code is all in `CallViewModel: ObservableObject`;

**Variables:**

```
var activeCall: VSLCall!
@Published var connectionStatus: String = ""
```

**Initializer:**

```
override init(){
        super.init()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.listen(_:)), name: Notification.Name.VSLCallStateChanged, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.buildCallView(_:)), name: Notification.Name.CallKitProviderDelegateInboundCallAccepted, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.buildCallView(_:)), name: Notification.Name.CallKitProviderDelegateOutboundCallStarted, object: nil)
    }
```

**Methods:**

```
func setCall(_ call: VSLCall) {
    self.activeCall = call
    self.activeCall.observe(\.callStateText) { (asd, change) in
        print("observing")
        print("\(String(describing: change.oldValue)) to \(String(describing: change.newValue)) for \(call.callId)")
    } 
}

@objc func listen(_ notification: Notification) {
       if let _ = self.activeCall {
           print(self.activeCall.callStateText)
       }    
}

@objc func buildCallView(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("inbound call")
    self.isOnCall = true 
}
```

**Problem:**

It prints out every thing except the `completionBlock` in `setCall(_:)`. `listen(_:)` function validates that the state of the `activeCall` is changing and I would want to use that directly, however it does not work correct all the time. It should be triggered when the call is answered with `callState` value of `.confirmed` but sometime it does. This how I will know that it is time start the timer.

Other point is, in the example project of the `VialerSIPLib` they used `self.activeCall.addObserver(_:)` and it works fine. The problem for that is it throws a runtime error at the method something like `didObservedValueChange(_:)` and logs `An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.`

Finally there is yellow warning at the `activeCall.observe(_:)` says

> `Result of call to 'observe(_:options:changeHandler:)' is unused`
>   which I could not find anything related to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Finally there is yellow warning at the activeCall.observe(_:) says
>
> ```
> Result of call to 'observe(_:options:changeHandler:)'
> ```

This is telling you what the problem is. The `observe(_:options:changeHandler:)` method is only [incompletely documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift). It returns an object of type `NSKeyValueObservation` which represents your registration as a key-value observer. You need to save this object, because when the `NSKeyValueObservation` is destroyed, it unregisters you. So you need to add a property to `CallViewModel` to store it:

```
class CallViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var callStateTextObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?
    ...
```

And then you need to store the observation:

```
func setCall(_ call: VSLCall) {
    activeCall = call
    callStateTextObservation = activeCall.observe(\.callStateText) { _, change in
        print("observing")
        print("\(String(describing: change.oldValue)) to \(String(describing: change.newValue)) for \(call.callId)")
    } 
}
```

You could choose to use the Combine API for KVO instead, although it is even less documented than the Foundation API. You get a `Publisher` whose output is each new value of the observed property. It works like this:

```
class CallViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var callStateTextTicket: AnyCancellable?
    ...

    func setCall(_ call: VSLCall) {
        activeCall = call
        callStateTextTicket = self.activeCall.publisher(for: \.callStateText, options: [])
            .sink { print("callId: \(call.callId), callStateText: \($0)") }
    }
```

There's no specific reason to use the Combine API in your sample code, but in general a `Publisher` is more flexible than an `NSKeyValueObservation` because Combine provides so many ways to operate on `Publisher`s.

---

Your error with `addObserver(_:forKeyPath:options:context:)` happens because that is a much older API. It was added to `NSObject` long before Swift was invented. In fact, it was added before Objective-C even had blocks (closures). When you use that method, all notifications are sent to the `observeValue(forKeyPath:of:change:context:)` method of the observer. If you don't implement the `observeValue` method, the default implementation in `NSObject` receives the notification and raises an exception.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I found the first solution in some blog and it works. I was replying but you did it first in a way that is more explanatory than I would. However, as I found you I have two more questions. There is a `setCallState(_:)` method in the library which handles this operation. It has `willChangeValueForKey()` at the top and `didChangeValueForKey`. Below `willChangeValueForKey` there is logger which indicates something like `callState will be from A to B.` Right after, my log in the `observe completion` is working and it says `Call state is changed to A`. Why is that happening?

Comment: They implemented this feature using `observeValue` and it is working but it does not make any sense to me. Secondly, Is there any way to handle the `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver` in a `Combine` way? I have searched a solution to that but no luck yet. Lastly -as a note-, Despite I have implemented the `observeValue(forKeyPath:of:change:context:)` method to my class, it was again throwing the related error. @rob mayoff

Comment: Regarding your first question, I can't say what's happening without studying the actual code. You could post a new question with more information if you want, but I cannot promise to answer it. Regarding your second question, you are looking for [`NotificationCenter`'s `publisher(for:object:)` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/3329353-publisher). Regarding your `observeValue` method, my guess is you are calling `super.observeValue` and you should not.

Comment: Well I will If I am not able to solve it. Lastly, I did try both and no luck, but I think I never will meed that method anymore. Thanks for your enlighting answer, again :)